# Появляется undefined в функции замыкания

Tags: javascript

Написала функцию, но не понимаю что именно является undefined. Подскажите в чем ошибка

```js
function logPerson(name, age, job) {
  return function() {
    console.log(`Person: ${name}, ${age}, ${job}`)
  }
}
let person1 = logPerson("Михаил", 22, "Frontend")
let person2 = logPerson("Елена", 19, "SMM")

console.log(person1())
console.log(person2())
```

Answer (score 3):

Функция, не возвращающая значение, по умолчанию возвращает undefined.

Т.к. у тебя написано `return function` то и возвращается этот самый undefined от результата выполнения функции

Наглядно на простейшем примере:

```js
console.log((function(){})());
```